# Trying to find even length substrings from index 0 onwards

Tags: c++, string, loops, while-loop, substring

I am trying to find even length substrings from the string "000000".It worked fine till index 2 after that it's not producing desired output.My IDE was showing exception unhandled at line :str2=str1.substr(i,k);

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "000000";
    string str2, str1;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < str.length())
    {
        int k = 2;
         str1 = str.substr(i);
        cout << "\n new substring from " << i << " pos is ";
        cout<<str1 << endl;
        int len = str1.length();
        cout << len << endl;

        while (k <= len)
        {
            cout << "\n" << i << " " << k;
         str2 = str1.substr(i, k);
            cout << endl << str2;


            k = k + 2;
            str2.clear();
        }
        i++;
        str1.clear();

    }

}
```

Comment: Actually what i meant is from that particular index value take even lenght strings.
Suppose stirng is 12345
From index 0: 12,1234
Index 1: 23, 2345
Index 2: 34
Index  3: 45
Index 4: nothing is possible
They are the above possible substrings

Answer (score 3):

It seems this statement

```
str2 = str1.substr(i, k);
                  ^^^
```

does not make sense.

You mean

```
str2 = str1.substr(0, k);
                  ^^^
```